# java code to find the biggest and smallest numbers out of 5 (not from array) using only 6 steps, each step you need to swap between 2 numbers

Tags: java, numbers, swap

I want to use the swapping between 2 numbers format in order to find the biggest and smallest numbers out of the 5 given by user.
I want to use only 6 steps but I reached each time to more than that. any suggestions to how to fix my code?

```
Scanner myScanner = new Scanner(System.in);

int a = myScanner.nextInt();
int b = myScanner.nextInt();
int c = myScanner.nextInt();
int d = myScanner.nextInt();
int e = myScanner.nextInt();
int tmp;

if (a > b) {
  tmp = b;
  b = a;
  a = tmp;
}

if (c > d) {
  tmp = c;
  c = d;
  d = tmp;
}

if (a > c) {
  tmp = a;
  a = c;
  c = tmp;
}

if (b > d) {
  tmp = b;
  b = d;
  d = tmp;
}

if (d > e) {
  tmp = d;
  d = e;
  e = tmp;
}

if (c > e) {
  tmp = c;
  c = e;
  e = tmp;
}

if (b > e) {
  tmp = b;
  b = e;
  e = tmp;
}

System.out.println(a);
System.out.print(e);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a duplicated code fragment. This will work if u remove the redundant code.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class UshtrimeRekursive {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner myScanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        int a = myScanner.nextInt();
        int b = myScanner.nextInt();
        int c = myScanner.nextInt();
        int d = myScanner.nextInt();
        int e = myScanner.nextInt();
        int tmp;

        if (a > b) {
            tmp = b;
            b = a;
            a = tmp;
        }

        if (c > d) {
            tmp = c;
            c = d;
            d = tmp;
        }

        if (a > c) {
            tmp = a;
            a = c;
            c = tmp;
        }

//        if (b > d) {
//            tmp = b;
//            b = d;
//            d = tmp;
//        }

        if (d > e) {
            tmp = d;
            d = e;
            e = tmp;
        }

        if (c > e) {
            tmp = c;
            c = e;
            e = tmp;
        }

        if (b > e) {
            tmp = b;
            b = e;
            e = tmp;
        }

        System.out.println(a);
        System.out.print(e);
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if the following code could be accepted as meeting the requirement to the number of "steps" because it contains 7 swap operations but only 3 or 4 swaps will actually be take place.  Also, the swap is implemented without a temporary variable with XOR-based one-liner:

```java
Random random = new Random();
// generate random values instead of user input
int a = random.nextInt(1000);
int b = random.nextInt(1000);
int c = random.nextInt(1000);
int d = random.nextInt(1000);
int e = random.nextInt(1000);
System.out.println(Arrays.asList(a, b, c, d, e));

if (e < a) {
    a = (e ^= a ^= e) ^ a;
}

if (b < a) {
    a = (b ^= a ^= b) ^ a;
} else if (b > e) {
    b = (e ^= b ^= e) ^ b;
}

if (c < a) {
    a = (c ^= a ^= c) ^ a;
} else if (c > e) {
    c = (e ^= c ^= e) ^ c;
}

if (d < a) {
    a = (d ^= a ^= d) ^ a;
} else if (d > e) {
    d = (e ^= d ^= e) ^ d;
}

System.out.println("min = " + a);
System.out.println("max = " + e);

System.out.println(Arrays.asList(a, b, c, d, e));
```

Example output

```
[629, 941, 339, 496, 366]
min = 339
max = 941
[339, 629, 366, 496, 941]
```